# Is it possible to use openni skeleton tracker for Stereo camera

Tags: openi-tracker, openni-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

IS it possible to use the skeleton tracking and hand gesture algorthims in the openni package to be used for a stereo camera?Thanking you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10970/is-it-possible-to-use-openni-skeleton-tracker-for-stereo-camera/) by [avin111](https://answers.ros.org/users/56/avin111/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2011-08-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think this is impossible.

In principle, you should be able to write an OpenNI module for your stereo camera that provides image and depth generators, and hook that up to NITE through OpenNI. There's a thread about that on openni-dev [here](http://groups.google.com/group/openni-dev/browse_thread/thread/13b2922faa59b492) you might want to follow up on.

In practice, I *think* (it's possible I'm wrong on this) that NITE links directly against the Sensor module for PrimeSense's chip instead of going through the OpenNI middleware. In that case, you can only use NITE with devices using PrimeSense's technology (Kinect, Asus Xtion Pro, etc.).

---

Originally posted by [Patrick Mihelich](https://answers.ros.org/users/180/patrick-mihelich/) with karma: 4336 on 2011-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [avin111](https://answers.ros.org/users/56/avin111/) on 2011-09-12**:
@Patrick i did not understand whether we can use stereo camera for tracking using openni_tracker.Thanking you..